# Selecting ANY from multiple columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to query the database to return **any** row which matches a value from a list of possible values in 3 columns. Is this possible?

My table has the following columns: id, ans1, ans2, ans3

And this is my attempt at a query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE 
  ans1 IN ("Yes", "No", "Maybe") OR 
  ans2 IN ("Yes", "No", "Maybe") OR 
  ans3 IN ("Yes", "No", "Maybe");
```

The 3 columns can each be *null*, and I only want to return a row if it contains a value from the list `("Yes","No","Maybe)` in **one** (or more) of the columns. The query executes successfully (without syntax errors) but only returns a row where a value exists in **all** columns.

For example:

```
INSERT INTO table 
 (ans1,ans2,ans3)
VALUES
 ("Yes","No","Maybe"),
 (null,"Yes",null),
 (null,null,"Yes");
```

I would like the query to return all 3 rows, but instead it only returns the 1st row as each column contains a matching value.

Comment: Does the query you've tried not work? If that's the case, what's wrong with it?

Comment: If the problem is you only want one result, a limit 1 on the end of that query will do the trick ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm looking for all rows as per my edit above.

Comment: We don't understand what the problem is -- please post actual and desired query results.

Comment: Fair enough. I've edited my question. Thanks for taking the time to consider this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly an answer, but it's too long for a comment.

Your query should work exactly how you want it to work.

Below is an example of your query, with your data, doing what you want it to do.

So what's the problem?

```
mysql> create table your_table (
    ->   ans1 varchar(10) null,
    ->   ans2 varchar(10) null,
    ->   ans3 varchar(10) null
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> INSERT INTO your_table (ans1,ans2,ans3) VALUES ('Yes','No','Maybe'),(null,'Yes',null),(null,null,'Yes');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> 
mysql> SELECT * 
    -> FROM your_table 
    -> WHERE 
    ->   ans1 IN ('Yes', 'No', 'Maybe') OR 
    ->   ans2 IN ('Yes', 'No', 'Maybe') OR 
    ->   ans3 IN ('Yes', 'No', 'Maybe');
+------+------+-------+
| ans1 | ans2 | ans3  |
+------+------+-------+
| Yes  | No   | Maybe |
| NULL | Yes  | NULL  |
| NULL | NULL | Yes   |
+------+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, folks. It was correct all along. Thanks Ike and everyone for your time! **face palm**

Answer (score 0):

If the choices are "Yes", "No", "Maybe", and NULL, then this query should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ans1 IS NOT NULL
  OR ans2 IS NOT NULL
  OR ans3 IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Downvoter, are you saying this query won't work?

Comment: Thanks, but I still need to specify a value to search for, not the absence of a value.

Comment: If you have four values, it's simpler to test the absence of one value versus the inclusion of three values. You found this unhelpful?